# Looking for a tool can run javascript in my computer

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I have to test some javascript code, that I use [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com), but it's not always convenient.

I hope there is a GUI tool can let me run javascript in my computer. I paste some javascript code into it and click 'RUN', that it will show me result.

Is there such a tool?

---

**UPDATE**

If I use browser, I need to create a html file first, that's not convenient. I think what I want is a offline version of jsbin.com.

Comment: http://javascript.open-libraries.com/development/debugging/9-great-javascript-debugging-tools/

Comment: open chrome -> press ctrl+shift+j -> select console -> paste code -> hit enter. No need to write a html file first.

Comment: Should be careful if input multi-lines, press 'shift+enter' to open new line

Comment: For anyone viewing this after 2011, node.js or io.js is how you run browser-less javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Browser will support to run your javascript, and most of the browser has add-on or plugins to debug your script. Only you need a editor to create your js file

or

you can use jsfiddle to test your code with multiple ajax framework.

Answer (score 2):

You only need two things:

- notepad.exe, or a similar text editor
- a web browser

I expect you already have those...  ;-)

Comment: with chrome/firebug console you don't even need notepad ;P

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across another option that maybe useful to you - [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a server side javascript engine that you can download and run on your local machine. It has a REPL mode if you invoke it without passing a javascript file to it. From this mode you can load javascript files directly and run them from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people on SO use www.jsfiddle.net. It lets you set up html, css and javascript as well as import external files to reference.

Comment: If jsbin.com isn't convenient then jsfiddle.net is unlikely to be, either...

Comment: I feel like jsbin.com is less usable than jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer to run JavaScript outside a browser, you could use [node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/). It has an interactive console, which would probably be great for what you're looking for.

Or if you're on Windows, you can use [wscript](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_runfromwindowsbasedhost.mspx?mfr=true), which is included with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

OK so you want to be able to code and run javascript directly without needed to call it in an HTML file and then load the file in your browser.

If the code is a short snippet then as Yoshi has pointed out earlier - modern browsers like chrome and firefox with firebug (my favorite) allow you directly run JS snippets on the browser javascript console.

This may be a little more tedious for larger scripts, so I think you should look for a javascript IDE which will give some debugging options as well. Have a look at the [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/) - it is available as a chrome plugin and is essentially an IDE in the cloud, but it has an offline mode you can use when you are disconnected. It is based on an open source AJAX code editor called [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/). You can see some of the capabilities in these [screencasts](http://vimeo.com/user5080429/videos/sort%3adate).